# N-dimensional convex hull qhull algorithm optimality

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, convex-hull

Why **quick hull** algorithm works with farthest point in *outside set* of facet instead of working with point, which gives maximum volume for simplex, resultant from the facet and the point?

If points are uniformly distributed in space (general case), then *largest volume* point potentially provide greater amount of cutoff points (which is not *above* the newly created facets) on each step. [Note](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822741/), that N-dimensional *oriented volume* proportional to simple determinant, but 1-dimensional *signed distance* additionally requires calculation of (N-1)-dimensional *oriented volume* ("square") for the facet, wich, in turn, imply determinant calculation of two non-square matrices dot-product.

Comment: If the base is held constant, maximizing the volume or the distance to the base are equivalent objectives (volume = base area x altitude)

Comment: You are right. It is truth. It is obvious, but I not seen.